# Compiled Legacy C++ Code in Visual Studio 2015 TCHAR issues

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015, tchar

I am working on some legacy code that I am not too familiar with. I encountered an error when I recompiled my project in visual studio 2015 from visual studio 2012.

I am having reference errors to function "_getts", which is normally part of 
"tchar.h".

[image]

I compared my visual studio 2012 installation to my 2015 installation and I see that the header file "tchar.h" is no longer in the shipping install. After further research, I see that Microsoft released the "Universal CRT" that now includes some of those header files that I see were removed from 2015. In the Microsoft documentation, I see that Visual Studio 2015 still clearly references "tchar.h".

I figure this is something so simple that I am clearly overlooking. If there is any good documentation that I missed also please do provide.

Thanks

Comment: gets() has been removed from the C11 and C++11 standards, its built-in buffer overflow bug made it entirely too dangerous.  You'll need to move to `_getts_s()`, it takes an extra argument that specifies the buffer size.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_getts` is just a macro definition, that's why the linker can't find it. Try defining the macro before `main()`:

```
#define _getts _getws
```

Comment: That worked for me to get rid of the error. Just out of curiousity, I was wondering why running with the vs 14.0 toolset would cause the error but the vs 11.0 toolset it would not give me the compile error? Also, I just saw that "tchar.h" got moved into the Windows Universal CRT so that answers another one of my questions.

Comment: @user3596611 The v140 might have some breaking changes (especially as they introduced the Univesal CRT), but I'm pretty sure that they wouldn't dare to remove `TCHAR`. Probably a bug or something else, I can't judge without the code. If my answer helped you please mark it as the answer.

Comment: I forgot to update this thread, but this issue was the result of the breaking changes with the Universal CRT. I had to do some reading and get caught up with the changes for v140.

Answer (score 0):

The `_getts` macro used to resolve to either `gets` (ANSI) or `_getws` (Unicode) depending of the charset setting. Both functions have been retired in VC++ 2015, along with the macro itself.

From [Breaking Changes in Visual C++ 2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531344.aspx):

> The gets and _getws functions have been removed. The gets function was removed from the C Standard Library in C11 because it cannot be used securely. The _getws function was a Microsoft extension that was equivalent to gets but for wide strings. As alternatives to these functions, consider use of fgets, fgetws, gets_s, and _getws_s.